# Why "an inherited constructor is not a candidate for initialization from an expression of the same or derived type"?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor

I expected this to work

```
struct Parent
{
    Parent ();

    Parent (const Parent &);
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
    using Parent::Parent;
};

Parent p;

Child c (p);
```

`Child` inherits all of `Parent`'s constructors, right?

Including `Parent::Parent(const Parent &)`?

```
x.cpp:15:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Child::Child(Parent&)’
 Child c (p);
           ^
x.cpp:5:2: note: candidate: Parent::Parent(const Parent&)
  Parent (const Parent &);
  ^~~~~~
x.cpp:10:16: note:   inherited here
  using Parent::Parent;
                ^~~~~~
x.cpp:10:16: note:   an inherited constructor is not a candidate for initialization from an expression of the same or derived type
x.cpp:8:8: note: candidate: Child::Child()
 struct Child : public Parent
        ^~~~~
```

Why can't I construct a `Child` from a `Parent`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inheriting a constructor doesn't prevent the default copy constructor of `Child` from being generated by the compiler.

This implies that you have a `Child::Child(const Child&)` which is hiding the inherited constructor that can't be chosen by lookup resolution, as [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) explains:

> if an inherited constructor matches the signature of one of the constructors of Derived, it is hidden from lookup by the version found in `Derived`. If one of the inherited constructors of `Base` happens to have the signature that matches a copy/move constructor of the `Derived`, **it does not prevent implicit generation of `Derived` copy/move constructor** (which then hides the inherited version, similar to using operator=).

In §12.9 of C++11 ISO standard is it stated:

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor
>   having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter**, a constructor is implicitly
>   declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
>   signature in the class where the using-declaration appears.

Comment: I don't think the inherited constructor is being hidden, they don't have the same signature.

Comment: it's hidden in the sense that it's not inherited at all, there is no `Child::Child(const Parent&)` in the final class because the compiler is not generating it, since there's already a `Child::Child(const Child&)`

Comment: Maybe I'm being confused by your wording, the compiler would not auto-generate a `Child::Child(const Parent&)` in any case? You would need to define that yourself?

Comment: @Mansoor The compiler generates `Child::Child(const Child&)`.  Because it does so, `Child::Child(const Parent&)` is not created because as this code shows, you would create a child from a parent and non of the child part of the class would be initialized.  If you want that behavior, you have to manually do it.

Comment: @NathanOliver " Because it does so, Child::Child(const Parent&) is not created", not created by who? The compiler would not do it by default and it is not defined in the Child class?

Comment: @Mansoor by the `using Parent::Parent` directive which tells the compiler to inherit constructors from parent class, indeed.

Comment: @Mansoor Having `using Parent::Parent;` basically says hey compiler, pretend you have `Child::Child(const Parent&)` and call `Parent (const Parent &);`.  But because the compiler will automatically generate a copy constructor for `Child` (`Child::Child(const Child&)`), the copy constructor hides the synthetic constructor the compiler would make from the inheritance.

Comment: Note that the specification for inheriting constructors has significantly changed after C++11 (in C++17 as a Defect Report)

Answer (score 5):

This is essentially [CWG issue 2356](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2356): Base class copy and move constructors should not be inherited.

[[over.match.funcs]/p9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-9) now says:

> A constructor inherited from class type C ([class.inhctor.init]) that has a first parameter of type “reference to cv1 P” (including such a constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of candidate functions when constructing an object of type cv2 D if the argument list has exactly one argument and C is reference-related to P and P is reference-related to D.