# Can not create a wrapper around std::string that results in only "syntax sugar"

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdstring

I know that std::string [is not designed for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/555633/8711400), however, I wonder why this class definition doesn't compile:

```
using std::string;
class ExtendedString: public string
{
public:
    using string::string;
    ExtendedString left(size_type n) const {
        return substr(0, n>size()?size():n);
    }
};
```

I get this error:

```
../../src/capel-tool.cpp:21:17: error: could not convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::substr(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int](0, ((n > ((const ExtendedString*)this)->ExtendedString::<anonymous>.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size()) ? ((const ExtendedString*)this)->ExtendedString::<anonymous>.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size() : n))’ from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘ExtendedString’
```

I expected that the `left` function would use any default constructor from std::string.

Even if I add an explicit constructor like this:

```
using std::string;
class ExtendedString: public string
{
public:
    using string::string;
    ExtendedString left(size_type n) const {
        return substr(0, n>size()?size():n);
    }

    explicit ExtendedString(const std::string &s);
};
```

I still get the same error.

Only when I add a normal constructor:

```
using std::string;
class ExtendedString: public string
{
public:
    using string::string;
    ExtendedString(const std::string &s);
    ExtendedString left(size_type n) const {
        return substr(0, n>size()?size():n);
    }
};
```

The code compiles ok.

Now imagine I want to make the same with a class that is designed for inheritance. Can not I just create this kind of wrapper in a way that the classes can be used interchangeablily without the need to create constructors thad would be created and called instead of being only "syntax sugar"

**EDIT 1:**

This [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926023/why-an-inherited-constructor-is-not-a-candidate-for-initialization-from-an-expr) does explain why my code does not work, but it does not propose any alternatives, as the accepted question does.

Comment: The `explicit` version should work if you use it: `return ExtendedString{substr(0, n>size()?size():n)};`

Comment: An explicit constructor needs to be invoked explicitly.  If you are attempting something like extension methods, I suggest a wrapper struct or a freestanding function.  (C++23 has another nice alternative with deduced this, if you can use that.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "an inherited constructor is not a candidate for initialization from an expression of the same or derived type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926023/why-an-inherited-constructor-is-not-a-candidate-for-initialization-from-an-expr)

Comment: If a class is designed for inheritance, then it is probably not designed for copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `substr` returns a `std::string`, not an `ExtendedString`. No implicit conversion exists between the types, so that return statement cannot compile.
There is an implicit conversion up the inheritance hierarchy, i.e. you can convert `ExtendedString` to `std::string`, but not the other way around.

To solve this for just your `left` function:

- you could make the constructor implicit: `ExtendedString(const std::string&)`
- construct explicitly: `return ExtendedString(substr(...))`

However, in general, what you're trying to do is just not nicely possible in C++. Every member function that you inherit from `std::string` is not going to return `ExtendedString`, so you have the wrong interface. C++ gives you no way of defining *extension methods*, which is the feature you're imitating.

#### *"Clean"* Alternatives

- create an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `ExtendedString`, but this results in unnecessary copying

  - note: this is what you've done when declaring `ExtendedString(const std::string &s);`
- inherit privately from `std::string` or better yet, wrap it as a member

  - create wrapper functions for every member function that `std::string` has, and make them take/return `ExtendedString` where necessary
- just create free functions (see below)

```cpp
std::string left(const std::string& s, std::size_t n) {
    return s.substr(0, std::min(s.size(), n));
}
```

As annoying as it is to sometimes call `str.function()` and sometimes `function(str)`, that inconsistency is a small price compared to any alternative.